# Pandas Dataframe to jsonlines grouping by columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

```
data = {
'my_index': [1, 2],
'start': ['2023-12-28 00:00:00', '2023-12-29 00:00:00'],
'target': [['value1', 'value2'], ['value3']],
'dynamic_feat': [[['feat1', 'feat2'], ['feat3']], [['feat4']]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

expected jsonlines format:

```
{
    "my_index": 1, 
    "features": {
                    "start": "2023-12-28 00:00:00", 
                    "target": [], 
                    "dynamic_feat": [[]]
                }
}
...
```

I have a data that requires 1 column to be independent key while the rest of the columns to be grouped as "features". What is the best way to achieve this?

The data is huge so I can't do simple iteration to achieve this. Initially I used to_json to create the portion of features, but now I need to match it back to my_index. Not sure if there is any sleek way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to `apply` a function to convert each row into a multi-level dict, then convert to json on a line-by-line basis:

```
out = (df
    .apply(lambda r:{ 'my_index' : r['my_index'], 'features' : r.drop(index='my_index').to_dict() }, axis=1)
    .to_json(orient='records', lines=True)
)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "my_index":1,
  "features":{
    "start":"2023-12-28 00:00:00",
    "target":["value1","value2"],
    "dynamic_feat":[["feat1","feat2"],["feat3"]]
  }
}
{
  "my_index":2,
  "features":{
    "start":"2023-12-29 00:00:00",
    "target":["value3"],
    "dynamic_feat":[["feat4"]]
  }
}
```

If you might have multiple lines for each `my_index` value, you can groupby `my_index`, converting the other columns into a dict, then converting the resultant series into json on a line-by-line basis. This gives a list of `features` instead of the single entry above.

```py
out = (df
    .groupby('my_index')
    .apply(lambda g:g.drop(columns='my_index').to_dict('records'))
    .reset_index(name='features')
    .to_json(orient='records', lines=True)
)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "my_index":1,
  "features":[
    {
      "start":"2023-12-28 00:00:00",
      "target":["value1","value2"],
      "dynamic_feat":[["feat1","feat2"],["feat3"]]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "my_index":2,
  "features":[
    {
      "start":"2023-12-29 00:00:00",
      "target":["value3"],
      "dynamic_feat":[["feat4"]]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nick! I came up with 

`data_to_dict = data.apply(lambda row: {
    START: row[START],
    TARGET: row[TARGET],
    DYNAMIC_FEAT: row[DYNAMIC_FEAT]
}, axis=1).to_dict()`

`final_transformed_data = [{"my_index": index, "features": data} for index, data in merged_to_dict.items()]`

but was still looking for a way to use the `.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)` as is. This is perfect. Thank you for sharing your insights!

Comment: @tmhs no worries - I'm glad I could help. I hope this is performant enough for your needs.